# How do I prevent directory browsing for all but valid users in .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, .htaccess

I'd like to allow directory browsing for users logged in via HTTP Basic authentication but prevent it for anonymous users. Is there a way to do this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule .? - [F,L]
```

You'll need to chain together as many `index.foo` types as you use.

This is assuming that by 'logged in user' you mean someone logged in using HTTP BASIC authentication.  If you mean someone logged in to a custom authentication mechanism, you'd need to hook a rewrite map into that, which probably isn't worth the effort; at that point I'd put an `index.foo` in all of my directories that checked for my custom authentication and sent an index or not, depending.

Answer (score -1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Explains exactly how to do that.  The Require parameter will be what you want to look at.

Comment: I misread the question the same way, first.  He's not asking how to control overall access to his site; he's asking about allowing or denying directory indexes.